# How to loop inside a loop that runs with an uneven (1 more or less than the specified number) number in JS;

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express, ejs

I am working on a project for a small theatre group and I am trying to get this loop to run correctly.

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Meet our Board of Directors!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<% let cards = 5;
let totalCard = 0;
for(i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
if (i % 3 === 0) { %>
  <div class="card-group text-center">

  <% for(let numCards = 0;  numCards < 3 || totalCard === cards; numCards++) { %>
    <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% totalCard++} %>

  </div>
<% numCards = 0; } } %>


<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Ok, the first loop runs great!

```
for(i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
if (i % 3 === 0) { %>
  <div class="card-group text-center">
<% } } %>
```

But the inside loop is what is getting me

```
<% for(let numCards = 0;  numCards < 3 || totalCard === cards; numCards++) { %>
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
<% totalCard++} %>
```

Essentially, I want it to create at least three cards inside the

```
<div class="card-group text-center">
```

[Here is what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHWpC.png)

Here is the hard-coded results I am looking for

```
<!-- First Div Generated -->
<div class="card-group text-center">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second Div Generated -->
<div class="card-group text-center">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you show a sample of the desired result?

Comment: @Barmar https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHWpC.png

Comment: Not an image, show the HTML you're trying to generate. And put it in the question.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, I added in a hard-coded version of the results I am looking for

Comment: Is there more to this than wanting 3 cards in each card-group?

Comment: Of course, the last card-group will have less than 3 cards if the number of cards isn't a multiple of 3.

Comment: Ah, I should've specified... I want at least three card (or more if I change my mind) per card-group.

Comment: Now I'm confused. The image and HTML have exactly 3 cards in the first group and 2 in the second group.

Comment: When I add a database, I don't want any errors when a third card is added to the second div if I have 5 objects in the DB already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <% let cards = 5, perRow = 3; %>
 <% for(let row = 0; row < cards/perRow + 1; row++){ %>
    <div id= "outer">
      <% for(let i = 0; i < 3 && i + row * perRow < cards; i++){ %>
        <div id = "inner" ></div>
     <% } %>   
    </div>      
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you chunk out your array beforehand if possible. Then, you can run a normal nested loop to print each group to the page (loop through the card groups to create the rows, then inside each iteration loop through that group's cards)

```js
var cards = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

var cardgroups = []

while(cards.length > 0){
  let chunksize = cards.length < 3 ? cards.length : 3 //as long as more than 3 exist, grab the next group of 3
  
  cardgroups.push(cards.splice(0, chunksize)) //push the next chunk into the array
}

console.log(cardgroups)
```

Comment: I am going to use a database and use the length of the object to determine the cards length. I decided to pre-write the code before I write the database to test if it works, most of the variables will be removed

Comment: Ok, well no matter the variables involved, you should be able to run something like that against your array first in your templating section to prep the data, along with any other alterations you might want to make in that loop.

Comment: Ok, I'll be sure to do that.